# How would I get the value out of an ID a dynamically created div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value (or find a better way) to get the value out of a div that I'm creating dynamically, my goal is to get the homeId and awayId out of the inputs so that I can use them in the ajax call below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Is there a good/better way to use the variables from above in my click function below?

```
getGames().done(function(results){
        $.each(results, function (i, gameData){
            $.each(gameData, function(key, game){

                var gamesHome = game.home_team_conference;
                var gamesAway = game.away_team_conference;


                if(gamesHome == "Big Ten" || gamesAway == "Big Ten"){

                    var gameId = game.id;
                    var homeTeam = game.home_team;
                    var awayTeam = game.away_team;
                    var pointTotal = game.total_points_bet;
                    var gameTime = game.game_time_hour;
                    var gameDate = game.game_time_date;
                    var homeId = game.home_team_id;
                    var awayId = game.away_team_id;
                    var network = game.broadcast_network;
                    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
                    var hueTwo = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';


                $('.wrapper').append('\
                    <div id="'+ gameId +'" class="main-wrapper col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">\
                    <div class="game-cards">\
                    <div class="chart-container">\
                    <canvas id="'+ homeTeam +'" width="500" height="500"></canvas>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="right-info">\
                    <h4>' + awayTeam + '<br>' + " @ " + '<br>' + homeTeam +'</h4>\
                    <h5 id="time-channel">'+ gameDate +' @ ' + gameTime  + '<br>' + ' On ' + network +'</h5>\
                    <div class="total-points-live">\
                    <h5>Total Points Bet</h5>\
                    <h5 id="point-total">'+ pointTotal +'</h5>\
                    <p>'+ awayTeam +'</p>\
                    <input class="bet-input-away" data-away-id="'+ awayId +'" data-team-type="'+ awayTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmountAway" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                    <p>'+ homeTeam +'</p>\
                    <input class="bet-input-home" data-home-id="'+ homeId +'" data-team-type="'+ homeTeam +'" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="betAmountHome" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                    <p class="bet-button" gameid="'+ gameId +'">Click To Place Bet</p>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    </div>\
                    ');

                }

            });

        });
    });
    // This is the click function that sends the bet to the server. 
    $('.wrapper').on('click', '.bet-button', function() {
        debugger;
        var self = $(this);
        var gameId = self.attr('gameid');
        var awayVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountAway]').val();
        var homeVal = $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountHome]').val();
        var awayId = $('#' + gameId + '.bet-input-away').attr('data-away-id');
        var homeId = $('#' + gameId + '.bet-input-home').attr('data-home-id');



        // var awayId = $('.bet-input-away').attr();
        // var homeId = $('.bet-input-home').attr(homeId);


        // This is what sends the bet to the server.
        $.ajax({
              url: "https://--------.islandshore.net/dbdata/bet/new/1/"+ gameId +"/"+ homeId +"/"+ homeVal +"",
              type: "get",
              success: function(response) {
                $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountHome]').val(''); //This resets the value box
                $('#' + gameId + ' input[name=betAmountAway]').val(''); //This resets the value box
              },
              error: function(xhr) {
                console.log('xhr')
              }
        });

        console.log(awayId);
        console.log(homeId);
        console.log(gameId);
        console.log(homeVal);
        console.log(awayVal);
    });
```

So far what is working is the awayVal and the homeVal, but I can't seem to get the homeId or awayId to work.

Comment: Can you explain more, something like this?  var awayId = attr('data-away-id');

Comment: `$('#' + gameId + '.bet-input-home').data('home-id');` i mislooked try like this

Comment: @guradio it's still returning as undefined

Comment: missing a space in 2 selectors before `.bet-input-away` and `.bet-input-home`

Comment: @charlietfl I'm confused by what you mean there.

Comment: Your concatenated selector would look like `$('#gamId.bet-input-away')` but should be like : `$('#gamId .bet-input-away')`. Need the space in order to look for those classes as descendants of the id element

Comment: @charlietfl holy crap, that is what it was, thank you so much! Why did that screw things up though?

Comment: @charlietfl put this in as the answer and I'll mark it as correct, thanks for your help!

Comment: Because without the space it looks for an elemet with that id AND that class.... not a descendant

Comment: @charlietfl so is the best way I am doing this or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing spaces in 2 selectors. The difference of which means you are looking for a single element with that id **and** that class vs looking for the class somewhere inside the element with the id

```
var awayId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-away').attr('data-away-id');
var homeId = $('#' + gameId + ' .bet-input-home').attr('data-home-id');
                            // ^^ add spaces
```

Instead of doing repetitive `$('#' + gameId + ...` store a reference once to the wrapper element and use find() for all the other elements

```
var $wrapper = $('#' + gameId);
// find() example
var awayId = $wrapper.find('.bet-input-away').attr('data-away-id');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Using the `$wrapper` approach will make code more legible and help alleviate such concatenation issues

Comment: Also note that it is far more efficient than searching the dom each time you need the same element. Good rule of thumb is if you need the same selector more than once...store the object in a variable